# Windows Click to focus without clicking inside

Tags: windows, window-manager, mouse-click, window-focus

I'd like to implement functionality such that I can click click anywhere on an unfocused window to focus it without triggering anything inside. I'm not talking about hover / focus-follows-mouse.

Is there a way or app that does this?

Comment: Click on the Windows "decorations", e.g., the title bar (avoiding the close, maximize and restore buttons). Not ideal, admittedly, which is why I use Alt-tab, or Windows (system key)-tab. Win-*n*, where *n* is a number (not Number Pad) key.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same behavior also in Windows:

If you click on the title or the edges of the window there will
be no click event on the contained app. A click event will arrive
only if you click inside the window.

Note that gaining the focus will still cause a focus-gained event.

Comment: Oh okay I guess I was wrong. Been a while. Still looking for a solution I described if anyone has any. Thank you

Comment: Please describe better your problem and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: That clicking on an unfocused window will focus it without triggering anything inside. I want this to be true for all windows; it  must be focused to interact with anything within the app borders.

Comment: That depends on how the window is treating the focus-gained event. Usually it al least creates a caret/cursor inside the current text field. I'm sure that this behavior is common to all graphical operating systems.

Comment: Yup. I have a specific situation and I'm not using a traditional mouse, and I think the functionality I described would make things a lot easier / comfortable for me. Do you have any ideas on how to create this?

Comment: I still haven't understood what functionality you're trying to create, since what I understand is a basic and common behavior for graphical systems.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following AutoHotkey script to do this, albeit with a key rather than a mouse click, in this case the F17 key. I guess you could assign it to a mouse click, although you'd want to check if the click was in the already-active window, and if so pass it through as a normal click. The script brings the window into focus/foreground, but doesn't click in it.

```
F17::
{
  MouseGetPos &xpos, &ypos, &wid
  WinActivate "ahk_id " wid
  return
}
```